# VueJs, send to method if checkbox is checked

Tags: vue.js

How can I send to `updateService` method a parameter indicates if the checkbox is checked or not?

```
<tr v-for="item in dataset" :key="item[0]" >                     
  <td>
    <input :checked="item[2]" type="checkbox" @change="updateService(item[0])" />
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass `$event` object as the second argument.

[Reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers).

```
<tr v-for="item in dataset" :key="item[0]" >                     
  <td>
    <input :checked="item[2]" type="checkbox" @change="updateService(item[0], $event)" />
  </td>
</tr>

export default {
  methods: {
    updateService(firstArgument, event) {
      console.log(event.target.checked);
    }
  }
}
```